# Adding every nested resource's parameter to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

I want to add every nested resource's parameter to an array. The main resource is `stream` and the nested resources are `videos`

```
@stream = Stream.friendly.find(params[:id])
@firstvideo = @stream.videos.first
```

I want to store

```
array[] = [firstvideo.video_id , secondvideo.video_id , thirdvideo.video_id .....]
```

`video_id` is a parameter for each video. How can I create a method that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to get the video IDs from an association:

```
ids = Stream.friendly.find(params[:id]).videos.pluck(:id)
```

This will generate a `select video_id from videos where ...` query and only instantiate the array of returned IDs, side-stepping the expensive process of building `Video` objects for each record.

If you have an already instantiated list of `Video` objects, use [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to produce an array of IDs:

```
ids = @videos.map(&:id) # equivalent to .map { |v| v.id }
```